# tmutil compare two external HDDs

Tags: backup, time-machine, external-disk

There are few TM backups: regulars are at continuously connected HDD, and another at external HDD which was used once to create a snapshot (same iMac). Now there is need to compare between two backups which separated by two days. I tried to use `tmutil compare` without any luck.

Seems like it doesn't want to do anything with external HDD. Can it be a valid reason? How to overcome if it is? And what are other probable causes that should be checked? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to compare them - what happens if there is a difference (which there will be as the backups will not be done at the same time)

Comment: +mmmmmm, yeah it should be and anticipated, the matter is **what difference** will there be found \
\
owner of the data isn't with us anymore, and his successors are sorting things out \
\
the single copy in question is most complete, but the HDD was possessed by a third party for some time \
the aim now is to understand if somebody was messing with files by analyzing difference in files that should be the same \
of course, added files (which number is small) will go uncontrolled

Comment: Sorry the text is slightly confusing are the comparisons between two backups on different disks?

Comment: +mmmmmm, yes, indeed. (Sorry tried to be short but describe everything that could be important.)

Comment: In that case any comparison tool will work - just find the correct folders - there is nothing time machine specific about this

Comment: +mmmmmm, that's mind changing news! Thanks a lot! I thought it's all highly specific.

Comment: If you have one tm backup go down to the dated filder then what is under there is a copy of the original disk - the magic of time machine  is that if you have 2 backups either looks like a complete copy but modt of the data is share only the changes needed to be copied

Comment: +mmmmmm, had to think some time on what you're saying... but maybe I got you. So, you propose to compare increments? But how do I get increment for one-time copy? It's a full snapshot of a particular moment, and I have nothing to `rsync` to make *delta* that could be compared with increment.

Sorry if I still misunderstand.

Comment: TM does not supply increments it supplies a full copy at each backup to all standard Unix tool (How it gets the full copy involves increments but that is behind the scenes)

Comment: +mmmmmm, sounds great, thank you! Will visit the place and try this in fortnight.

Comment: Make sure no one touches the machines until then